# Parallelization with ray not working as expected

Tags: python, parallel-processing, ray

I am a beginner with parallel processing and I currently experiment with a simple program to understand how Ray works.

```
import numpy as np
import time
from pprint import pprint
import ray

ray.init(num_cpus = 4) # Specify this system has 4 CPUs.

data_rows = 800
data_cols = 10000
batch_size = int(data_rows/4)

# Prepare data
np.random.RandomState(100)
arr = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=[data_rows, data_cols])
data = arr.tolist()

# Solution Without Paralleization
def howmany_within_range(row, minimum, maximum):
    """Returns how many numbers lie within `maximum` and `minimum` in a given `row`"""
    count = 0
    for n in row:
        if minimum <= n <= maximum:
            count = count + 1
    return count

results = []

start = time.time()
for row in data:
    results.append(howmany_within_range(row, minimum=75, maximum=100))
end = time.time()

print("Without parallelization")
print("-----------------------")
pprint(results[:5])
print("Total time: ", end-start, "sec")


# Parallelization with ray
results = []
y = []
z = []
w = []

@ray.remote
def solve(data, minimum, maximum):
    count = 0
    count_row = 0
    for i in data:
        for n in i:
            if minimum <= n <= maximum:
               count = count + 1
        count_row = count
        count = 0    
    return count_row

start = time.time()
results = ray.get([solve.remote(data[i:i+1], 75, 100) for i in range(0, batch_size)])
y = ray.get([solve.remote(data[i:i+1], 75, 100) for i in range(1*batch_size, 2*batch_size)])
z = ray.get([solve.remote(data[i:i+1], 75, 100) for i in range(2*batch_size, 3*batch_size)])
w = ray.get([solve.remote(data[i:i+1], 75, 100) for i in range(3*batch_size, 4*batch_size)])
end = time.time()

results += y+z+w

print("With parallelization")
print("--------------------")
print(results[:5])
print("Total time: ", end-start, "sec")
```

I am getting much slower performance with Ray:

```
$ python3 raytest.py 
Without parallelization
-----------------------
[2501, 2543, 2530, 2410, 2467]
Total time:  0.5162293910980225 sec
(solve pid=26294) 
With parallelization
--------------------
[2501, 2543, 2530, 2410, 2467]
Total time:  1.1760196685791016 sec
```

In fact, if I scale up the input data I get messages in the terminal with the pid of the function and the program stalls.

Essentially, I try to split computations in batches of rows and assign each computation to a cpu core. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

there are two main problems when it comes to multiprocessing (your code)

1. there's an overhead associated with spawning the new processes to do your work.
2. there's an overhead associated with transferring data between different processes.

in order to spawn a new process, a new instance of the python interpreter is created and initialized (due to the [GIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_interpreter_lock)). also when you transfer data between processes, this data has to be serialized/deserialized at the sender/receiver, which in your program is happening twice (once from main process to workers, and again from workers to the main process.), so in short your program is spending all it's time paying this overhead instead of doing the actual computation.

if you want to utilize the benefit of multiprocessing in python you should have more computation being done at the workers using as little data transfer as possible, the way I usually determine if using multiprocessing will be a good idea is if the task is going to take more than 5 seconds to complete on a single cpu.

another good idea to reduce data transfer is slicing your arrays in chucks (multiple rows) instead of a single row per function call, as each row has to be serialized separately, which adds extra overhead.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by "which in your program is happening twice (once from main process to workers, and again from workers to the main process.), so in short your program is spending all it's time paying this overhead instead of doing the actual computation."? Can you explain to me where this transfer takes place in the code and how I could avoid it?

Comment: Function input arguments and return have to be transferred, also there are other ways to transfer data between processes like queues if you want to transfer even more data, but in order to avoid data transfer you could Perhaps construct the data in your worker function, instead of passing it as an argument, for example if the data is read from disk, you can have the worker process read from disk instead of the main process, so the data doesn't have to be transferred across on function call.